# Нужна ли запятая после слова "метод"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятую после слова "метод"?

> Рентгенография действительно информативный метод и она покажет
> повреждение костных структур, но если боли в суставе вызваны
> поражением мягких тканей, например связок или сухожилий, то здесь уже
> нужно делать МРТ.

Comment: Да, запятая нужна. Это сложносочинённое предложение.